# UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal flips Vertically in Landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview

When in landscape, transitioning from one view (that's part of a Navigation Controller stack) to another as a modal view, with UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal set as the modalTransitionStyle, the view flips vertically in landscape mode.

Everything else about the look of the views is fine after the animation, though I did notice that the frame size of the views isn't changing which is causing issues in other places of my code as well. I figured if I fix whatever is making this particular flip vertical instead of horizontal, it will fix the other issue.

I assume it has something to do with the window itself not changing orientation, but I'm not sure that's it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talked to an Apple Engineer at WWDC and figured out the UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal does not work in landscape, it will flip what looks like in vertical.

The other issue I mentioned was because I wasn't adapting a frame to the view correctly.

Comment: Great mention of the Apple engineer @ WWDC.  I'm having this exact issue, and you've made me confident I should just switch to a different transition. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this if you use iOS7 custom view controller transition. The ViewController which initiates the transition should confirm to  protocols an implement the following methods.

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:  (UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    return (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)self;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    return (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)self;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0.7f;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];


    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    [containerView addSubview:fromVC.view];

    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    [containerView addSubview:toVC.view];

    UIViewAnimationOptions animationOption;

    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        animationOption = ([toVC.presentedViewController isEqual:fromVC])?UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom;
    }
    else {
        animationOption = ([toVC.presentedViewController isEqual:fromVC])?UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight;
    }

    [UIView transitionFromView:fromVC.view
                    toView:toVC.view
                  duration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                   options:animationOption
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                    }];
}
```

The transitioning delegate of the modal ViewController to be displayed should be set like this:
    [modalViewController setTransitioningDelegate:self];
For example this linke can be put in the prepareForSegue: method.

That's it.

Comment: I tried that in iOS8 but when it is presented it doesn't animate however it does animate when i dismiss it.