# Flip view controller horizontally while in landscape mode on the iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, viewcontroller

My iPad app is set to landscape mode. I tried to use `setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` to have the view controller flip horizontally, but it does so as if it is still in portrait. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What do you need here? The app to be only in Landscape from the start no matter what the current orientation is on the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

http://aseriesoftubes.com/articles/ipad-development-101-orientation/

check this sample tutorial..
it will help u..

changing between views would be an solution for u...

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought to set the modal view into the landspace mode like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have unfortunately. Do you think that would have fixed it normally? Does this mean there is probably a bug somewhere else?

Comment: Hum ok, I see what you mean now (I always confused with the horizontal axis symmetry). It seems that is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601317/uimodaltransitionstylefliphorizontal-flips-vertically-in-landscape. You'll have to do it yourself.